# Defining Spacemacs/Doom-like bindings with general.el and which-key, how to use :wk on all levels?

Tags: key-bindings, which-key

I'm trying to put together a config of my own after having used Spacemacs for a few years. To customize keybindings, and make them a bit Spacemacs-like, I'm trying out [general.el](https://github.com/noctuid/general.el). So far it seems to work rather well, except for one thing where the integration with `which-key` isn't quite as I'd hoped. On the other hand, I might just be doing it wrong.

In order to get multi-key bindings, like `SPC E y` to visit my yasnippet files, I've first created a "definer" with `SPC` as the leader key

```el
(general-create-definer mes/leader-def
  :keymaps '(normal insert visual emacs)
  :prefix "SPC"
  :non-normal-prefix "M-SPC")
```

using that I then define the next level, `E` in this case

```el
(mes/leader-def
  :infix "E"
  "" '(:ignore t :wk "Emacs")
  "y" '(:keymap mes-yasnippet-map :wk "yasnippet"))
```

The definition of `'mes-yasnippet-map` looks like this (I did a bit of reading on keybindings/keymaps and this seems to be a reasonable way of doing it)

```el
(define-prefix-command 'mes-yasnippet-map)
(general-def :keymaps 'mes-yasnippet-map
  "v" '(yas-visit-snippet-file :wk "visit snippet"))
```

When pressing `SPC` I'll first see "E -> Emacs", then pressing `E` I'll see "y -> yasnippet", then pressing `y` I expected to see "v -> visit snippet" but instead I see "v -> yas-visit-snippet-file".

First of all, is this a good way of defining Spacemacs-like keybindings using `general.el`, or is there a better way?

Second, if this is a good way, how do I get `which-key` to show what I want on all levels?

Comment: I'm too busy to write a formal answer in the following two weeks, you can refer to my [configuration](https://github.com/tshu-w/.emacs.d/blob/master/lisp/core-keybinds.el), general.el and which-key work very well together.

Comment: Please don't ask "Is this a good way...?" or "Is there a better way...?" - encourages opinion-based answers. And please don't pose multiple questions in the same post - one per post, please. Thx.

Comment: Thanks Tianshu Wang, your config looks like a very good resource indeed.

Comment: Drew, thanks for reminding me why I stopped asking questions on exchanges.

Answer (score 0):

Tianshu Wang's setup pointed out something that I didn't think of myself. I don't need to create a separate keymap for the binding with multiple keys. So what I ended up with was this a single definition of my keybindings

```el
(mes/leader-def
 :infix "E"
 "" '(:ignore t :wk "Emacs")
 "y" '(:ignore t :wk "yasnippet))
 "yv" '(yas-visit-snippet-file :wk "visit-snippet"))
```

I've since also adopted more of the setup I found in Tianshu's setup, in particular the [`tyrant-def`](https://github.com/tshu-w/.emacs.d/blob/master/lisp/core-keybinds.el#L36) and [`despot-def`](https://github.com/tshu-w/.emacs.d/blob/master/lisp/core-keybinds.el#L39). Doing that actually solved some other issues I had in setting up my keybindings with `general.el`.